# How to make jface data binding work both ways?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I'm trying to implement something similar to a property view in eclipse. That is also able to edit the properties of the selected object, and when the selection changes the displayed values should change as well. So I try to bind the Text fields to my model properties but for some reason the binding only works one way (view -> model). Any suggestions?

```
private org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text length;

private void initBinding(){
    DataBindingContext ctx = new DataBindingContext();

    IObservableValue<String> propertyLength = BeanProperties.value(SqlDataModel.class, "length", String.class)
            .observe(dataModel);
    ISWTObservableValue<String> widgetLength = WidgetProperties.text(SWT.Modify).observe(length);
    ctx.bindValue(widgetLength, propertyLength);
}
```

The model is a POJO

```
public class SqlDataModel {

    private String length;

    public String getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(String length) {
        this.length = length;
    }
    
    ...
```

Comment: There is no way for the data binding code to detect that the `length` value has changed when you use a POJO. You need to something like `WritebleValue` - see [this tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDataBinding/article.html)

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for answering, but I'm more confused after reading the tutorial.
Changed my model to:
`public class SqlDataModel {`

 `private WritableValue<String> length = new WritableValue<>();`

 `public String getLength() {`
  `return length.getValue();`
 `}`

 `public void setLength(String length) {`
  `this.length.setValue(length);`
 `}`
 
 ...
```
but now the binding does not work at all.